# WordPress: background image doesn't appear

Tags: wordpress, upload, background-image

I'm using wordpress 3.5.2 with the theme black label and have a problem with the background images. When I set a background image on a page, there is no problem with the upload. On the backend the uploaded image is shown as a thumbnail and I insert the image into post. But on the website itself all you can see is the loading circle.

http://hendrikrojas.meinsign.de/?page_id=2

I reinstalled wordpress several times and tried also different versions (3.6.1 as well). The theme's developer said it might be a problem with the installation. 
What do you think?

Thanks so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have, at least, a syntax error in your JS code

```
jQuery(function($){
$.supersized({
//Functionality
slideshow : 1, //Slideshow on/off
autoplay : , //Slideshow starts playing automatically
```

set a value for the `autoplay` field and all the others below that don't have a value.

I run a fixed function in Firebug and it worked.

for example:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$.supersized({
    //Functionality
    slideshow: 1, //Slideshow on/off
    autoplay: 0, //Slideshow starts playing automatically
    start_slide: 1, //Start slide (0 is random)
    random: 0, //Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
    slide_interval: 1, //Length between transitions
    transition: 0, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
    transition_speed: 5, //Speed of transition
    new_window: 0, //Image links open in new window/tab
    pause_hover: 1, //Pause slideshow on hover
    keyboard_nav: 1, //Keyboard navigation on/off
    performance: 1, //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
    image_protect: 1, //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
    image_path: 'http://hendrikrojas.meinsign.de/wp-content/themes/blacklabel/images/', //Default image path
    //Size & Position
    min_width: 0, //Min width allowed (in pixels)
    min_height: 0, //Min height allowed (in pixels)
    vertical_center: 1, //Vertically center background
    horizontal_center: 1, //Horizontally center background
    fit_portrait: 1, //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
    fit_landscape: 0, //Landscape images will not exceed browser width
    //Components
    navigation: 1, //Slideshow controls on/off
    thumbnail_navigation: 0, //Thumbnail navigation
    slide_counter: 0, //Display slide numbers
    slide_captions: 0, //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
    slides: [ //Background image
        {
            image: 'http://hendrikrojas.meinsign.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bg-projekte.jpg'
        }
    ]
});
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That sounds pretty awsome. Unfortunatly I don't understand much about jQuery and don't know where and how to past your script in. 
I'm sorry, but could you send me a step by step discription?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't. I don't know anything about your files. find in which file you have "$.supersized" and substitute the function with the one I gave you.